# What is the meaning of prefix "md" in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I just want to know the meaning so if somebody will ask I can answer that question.

Here are the examples `md-content, md-button`.

Comment: Why does this matter to you?..... Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask.

Comment: @B001 can you explain to me why not?

Comment: you couldn't explain why it matters to you and asked me why not.. Because it doesn't matter at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "md" stands for "[Material Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design)", a specific UI look-and-feel developed by Google in 2014.

These are not part of Angular itself, but part of a component library built in Angular: "a set of reusable, well-tested, and accessible UI components based on Material Design": https://material.angularjs.org/latest/

Comment: Appreciated answer sir. That is why I ask because I will not spin the wheel in my head what is the meaning of that. First thought is like Module-Directive for me. Thanks for the answer.